# Print Array elements with Indexes & Values

Tags: javascript

How to print the index number like this?

```
Array[0] = Yasir
Array[1] = Ahmed
Array[2] = Yousuf
```

[image]

Comment: ``arr.map((element, idx) => `Arrax[${idx}] = ${element}`).join('\n')``

Comment: Please copy-paste the expected output into the question and use the `{}` button in the question editor toolbar to format it as code, if appropriate. Do not post images that represent text when the text can be posted instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have data as an array of names, this will work for you:

```
arr.map((El,index) => `Array[${index}]-${el}`))
```